# What's Git.exe and do I need? (Newbie)

Tags: git

I just installed Visual Studio Code.
It gave a popup saying git.exe was missing.

Do I need? What's it for?
What am I missing if I don't get?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Git is a version control system.
You may ask what's a repository: that's commonly used when talking about an hosted project folder.

Git basically give you and your coworkers an efficient way to view what has been push, revert those push if needed, see what you've changed before pushing (compared to the last push), and way more. There is even some softs like gitKraken who provide a friendly UI for a better user experience.

It's commonly used by developpers to keep track on their work when they are developping with other peoples, basically.

If you want to know more, search for it on the internet you'll find plenty of git systems out there.

Talking about you needing it: it depends, if you are solo it's up to you and your organization to have your own git repository on a site like github for example, and if you are in a working group you'll 99% of the time use some kind of git equivalent because it's simply way more secure and easyer in terms of code/project management.

Also some IDEs implement git as a default feature, so Visual Studio is just trying to tell you "I'am sorry but you don't have git installed on your system, you won't be able to use git trought Visual Studio."

Comment: Git is a version control system. For me a repo is always offline.

Comment: True, i'am editting right now :) Thanks for pointing this out !

Comment: Also i may be wrong @evolutionxbox but (when talking about repositories) "hosted" is a correct term even if in facts "online" is not when i think about it twice... ?

Comment: I don’t think you’re wrong about hosted repos. I just think most people’s everyday interaction with them will be offline and local.

Comment: @evolutionxbox that's also what i tought, thanks again :)